# How to make specific column items in the list control to be editable?

Tags: mfc

I am having a listcontrol which intern consists of 4 columns.Now I wanna edit second column items in the list.How can I make it editable?I have seen many samples in code project and in many other forums ,In none of the forums I was given an simple solution.I can make it done but it is time consuming (by debugging),Is there any simple solution to make a specific column items in the list to be editable.(For Instance I want all the items in the second column to be editable)

Any suggestions can be appreciable..

Comment: Are you asking for only one entire column, or, some items in a specific column?

Comment: @rrirower For all the items in a specific column.

Comment: That capability is not native to a list control.  As was indicated, you'll need to write your own code, or, use a class specifically written to provide that capability.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253919/how-to-edit-columns-in-place-with-clistctrl

Answer (score 0):

This is your quick solution with in-place editing of all columns: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8112/CQuickList

Comment: I have gone through this also.Isn't any other way exist.

Comment: Gone through? Come on, this control is nice! There is no build-in support for in-place editing of subitems in the standard CListCtrl. Don't be so lazy! :)