# IN MFC CLISTCTRL a column should have an EDIT feature?

Tags: mfc

I am a beginner to MFC and C++ I want to have an edit option in one column I tried to overload these functions in the Classes but  the Edit Option is not working could any one help me on this what is the mistake I did ?

```
class CEditableListCtrl : public CListCtrl  
{  
public:  
    int GetRowFromPoint( CPoint &point, int *col ) const;  
    CEdit* EditSubLabel( int nItem, int nCol );  

    void OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);  
   void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);  

   void OnEndLabelEdit(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);  
    void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);  
};  

class CInPlaceEdit : public CEdit   
{  

public:   
    CInPlaceEdit(int iItem, int iSubItem, CString sInitText);   

    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides   
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CInPlaceEdit)     
    public: virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);      
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL  

public: virtual ~CInPlaceEdit();  

    // Generated message map functions  
protected:    
    //{{AFX_MSG(CInPlaceEdit)     
    afx_msg void OnKillFocus(CWnd* pNewWnd);      
    afx_msg void OnNcDestroy();  
    afx_msg void OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);   
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);      
    //}}AFX_MSG       

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()  

private:      
    int m_iItem;      
    int m_iSubItem;   
    CString m_sInitText;      
    BOOL    m_bESC;  
};
```

Comment: _...but the Edit Option is not working..._ - care to be more specific?  You've shown the class definitions, but, no executable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one column to be editable, you don't need to do much: make sure your list has an LVS_EDITLABELS style. This will allow you to edit text in column 0. If you need to edit different column - change visible column order using [CListCtrl::SetColumnOrderArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wd74ay.aspx)

Comment: Is it the same column in each row? Then my suggestion will work.

Comment: Depending on our selected row .any column of that particular row must become editable..is it possible through your approach?

Comment: @BharathKumar - no, but check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253919/how-to-edit-columns-in-place-with-clistctrl